# How to update value in iPhone settings when Toggle switch on in same settings view.

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7

I am playing one video and each time when I play am maintaining the count of that video and displaying that count in iPhone settings(through `Settings.bundle`). I added one `Toggle switch` to reset the count to Zero and one `Title` to display the count. Now my question is how can I make the count to zero when I reset(switch on) as according to me we can read/update values from iPhone settings in to our app OR we can update values from our app to iPhone settings. But my problem is I need to make count to zero when I reset(switch on) in same iPhone settings view. Please help me.